# Using grpc-dotnet as a simple 1-to-1 raw socket connection without web functionality

Tags: c#, client-server, grpc-dotnet

Using 'old' school grpc to setup simple client server communication channel (basic sockets) now seems impossible when using grpc-dotnet. It seems like this feature is not present anymore. Is this correct?

I would like to setup basic rpc communication without having web abilities (that is not used).
Is there a way to this?

Goal:
Utilizing rpc generation with proto's and setup basic socket communication.

Comment: Have you tried posting on their Github repo? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet

Comment: And when you say:
```
It seems like this feature is not present anymore
```
Could you please clarify what you tried, and how it failed?

Comment: Thx for your reply. Just a simple TCPListener, TCPClient with rpc enable would be sufficient. Previous version had simple ServerPort.    Now I get a complete WebServer which is unwanted.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without the ASP server functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can still build a simple gRPC server application using grpc-dotnet.

Follow the tutorial in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code

The server built by the above tutorial is a standalone server application that contains its own Kestrel web server. The fact that it is a web server is probably irrelevant to your application - it is just a means of providing the HTTP/2 server used by gRPC.